# Consulta sobre IDP GAM

Tags: genexus

**Genexus 17 u6
.Net**

Tengo un esquema de aplicaciones utilizando OAuth 2.0 mediante [IDP GAM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4w1lkF_2W0). Para llegar a eso configuré el server con este documento:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?46496,Server-side+configuration+for+SSO+in+Rest+applications

Y los clientes con este documento:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?46499,Client-side+configuration+for+SSO+in+Rest+applications

La autenticación desde cada cliente utilizando al server funciona perfecto. Ahora quiero pasar a definir permisos y roles para cada una de las webapp clientes y acá es donde me surgen dudas.

¿Se crean roles en la webapp server y en webapp cliente que se llamen igual o solo se crean roles en el server?

1. Si creo roles en el server, ¿Cómo le doy permisos sobre los objetos webpanel clientes?
2. Si creo los roles en la webapp cliente  con sus permisos sobre objetos webpanel. Cuando un usuario
   definido en el server se loguea a la app cliente, ¿GAM busca que los roles "traidos" desde el server se encuentren en el cliente y ahí mismo obtiene la información de permisos?

Answer (score 1):

Puedo darle de ejemplo como una de mis kb tiene paramatrizado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y debes asignar tu propio eventsubscription al iniciar sesion, algo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y puedes guiarte un poco con este wiki [wiki](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?37703,HowTo%3A%20Get%20user%27s%20additional%20information%20from%20the%20GAM%20Identity%20Provider)

Comment: Gracias Yester por tu comentario. Esta bárbaro como podemos enviar información adicional desde el server de autenticación a las aplicaciones clientes. En realidad yo estoy buscando específicamente manejar permisos y autorizaciones de GAM y no comprendo como es posible lograrlo.